# Сонорные и шумные согласные

Tags: фонетика

И вот уж начальник вскочил на коня. - Товарищ начальник, Возьмите меня! Я метко стреляю, без промаха бью, мне брат доверяет винтовку свою!
[ивóт  ýшн^ч áл'н' ик фск^чи'л н^к^н' á// - т^в áр ' и ш':  н^ч áл'н' ик/ в^з'м'и'т'ь м'ин' á jа м'э'ткъ стр'ил' áṷу/ б'э'спрóмъхъ б'jу/ мн'э' бр áт дъв 'ир ' á ṷьт в'интóфку св^jу ]
Сонорных-22
Шумных-42

Comment: >Сонорные и шумные гласные   

Вы точно уверены?

Comment: Ой!!!!Простите!Опечатка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы так. Только вот в транскрипции всё-таки- [ивóтуш ] , иначе было бы Ж, а не Ш.